# Ecto custom type in Phoenix Form?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using an Ecto custom type in one of my Phoenix application's schemas, like described [here](https://medium.com/@rcdilorenzo/creating-a-custom-ecto-duration-type-994e32ad4613) (specifically, making use of Postgres Ranges to specify a [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) of [times](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html), like "between 12:00-4:00"). I'm able to insert/retrieve from the database without a problem, but I'm having trouble coming up with a good way to present a form for the user using changesets and Phoenix forms.

So with a schema looks like this (`TimeRange` is the custom type):

```
  @primary_key false
  @foreign_key_type :binary_id
  schema "person_messaging_settings" do
    field :can_receive_email, :boolean, null: false
    field :can_receive_sms, :boolean, null: false
    field :allowed_hours, MyApp.Ecto.TimeRange
    belongs_to :person, Person
    timestamps()
  end
```

I can use [`inputs_for`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#inputs_for/4) for the `belongs_to` association, and ideally I could do something like this in my EEX template:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, Routes.settings_path(@conn, :update), fn f -> %>

  <!-- other field values -->

  <%= inputs_for f, :allowed_hours, fn ah -> %>
    <%= time_select ah, :upper %>
    <%= time_select ah, :lower %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But this complains because `inputs_for` is strictly for associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a raw untested idea with [virtual fields](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3).

Schema file:

```
schema "person_messaging_settings" do
  # ...
  field :allowed_hours_from, :time, virtual: true
  field :allowed_hours_to, :time, virtual: true
end

def changeset do
  record
  |> cast(attrs, [..., :allowed_hours_from, :allowed_hours_to])
  |> set_allowed_hours()
  |> validate_required([..., :allowed_hours])
end

defp set_allowed_hours(changeset) do
  case {get_field(changeset, :allowed_hours_from), get_field(changeset, :allowed_hours_to)} do
    {nil, nil} -> changeset
    {nil, _}   -> changeset
    {_, nil}   -> changeset
    {from, to} -> put_change(changeset, :allowed_hours, "#{from}-#{to}")
  end
end
```

And the form:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, Routes.settings_path(@conn, :update), fn f -> %>

  <!-- other field values -->

  <%= time_select f, :allowed_hours_from %>
  <%= time_select f, :allowed_hours_to %>
<% end %>
```

Although I don't know how you would populate the two `time_select`s when editing a saved timerange (decomposing the `:allowed_hours`). Perhaps somebody else does. Or you render a regular html input with the correct name and value.

Edit 3... Or would this work?

```
<%= time_select f, :allowed_hours_from, value: something(f.data.allowed_hours) %>
```

Comment: This worked fantastically! I'd completely forgot about virtual fields, thank you! 